# Installing gdm3 causes settings to crash, doesn't work on pre-existing accounts

Tags: linux, xubuntu, lightdm, gdm3

so on my fresh Xubuntu install (dual booting with macOS Catalina), I wanted to install gdm3.  I used the following commands:
`sudo apt-get install gdm3`

`sudo systemctl enable gdm3`

`sudo systemctl disable lightdm`

At this point, something weird happened - I expected my computer to shut down/restart.  However, that didn't happen.  I continued on, and then used `sudo apt-get purge lightdm` and then rebooted.

Now the following happened:
First, the admin account I was using to install and test stuff was still using lightdm.  However, the login/lock screen was using gdm3.  I created another account AFTER installing gdm3, and this account was using gdm3 as its display manager.  However, on this new account, while looking pretty, would not open settings: the app would just start, I would see a buffering circle spinning on its tab on the top bar, and then it would close.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this? tl'dr Switching to gdm3 doesn't change any accounts already using lightdm, and breaks settings.  Using `xfce4-settings-manager` in the terminal opens a settings page, but none of the apps inside work (clicking on any of them just closes the settings with an error message).

Answer (score 0):

purging/removing lightdm seems to also uninstall the desktop dependencies for xubuntu, reinstalling these back will return it back to normal and keep gdm3 as the selected display manager:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-core
```